# jsf <f:selectItems> itemVale and message bundle question

Tags: jsf, el

I have a form with a combo box populated like this:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{programHandler.validLanguages}" 
var="languageConstant" 
itemLabel="#{languageConstant.value}" 
itemValue="#{languageConstant}" />
```

I also have a message bundle defined:

```
<f:loadBundle basename="MessageResource" var="msg" />
```

My question is, my problem is the languageConstant.value returns a key from the database, for example LANG_ENGLISH, and I want to display the text value from the message bundle.

How do I do this?  For example, I guess I'm looking for something like this:

```
itemLabel="#{msg.[languageConstant.value]}"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. It's

```
itemLabel="#{msg[languageConstant.value]}"
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help!  Just FYI, I sent you a personal message on linkedin -- ttyl.